# docker-compose scale with nginx and without environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker-compose to describe the deployment of one of my application. The application is composed of a

- mongodb database,
- a nodejs application
- a nginx front end the static file of nodejs.

If i scale the nodejs application, i would like nginx autoscale to the three application.

Recently i use the following code snippet :

https://gist.github.com/cmoore4/4659db35ec9432a70bca

This is based on the fact that some environment variable are created on link, and change when new server are present.

But now with the version 2 of the docker-compse file and the new link system of docker, the environment variable doesn't exist anymore.

How my nginx can now detect the scaling of my application ?

```
version: '2'
services:
    nodejs:
        build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.nodejs
        image: docker.shadoware.org/passprotect-server:1.0.0
        expose:
            - 3000
        links:
            - mongodb
        environment:
            - MONGODB_HOST=mongodb://mongodb:27017/passprotect
            - NODE_ENV=production
            - DEBUG=App:*
    nginx:
        image: docker.shadoware.org/nginx:1.2
        links:
            - nodejs
        environment:
            - APPLICATION_HOST=nodejs
            - APPLICATION_PORT=3000
    mongodb:
        image: docker.shadoware.org/database/mongodb:3.2.7
```

Comment: I had the same issue, I did a similar thing to your sed replace to update the upstream, searching the web I could find those two other solutions but they are not using Nginx. This first project is looking for adoption by other developers and uses HAProxy https://github.com/docker-flow/docker-flow-proxy and the other approach would be to use Traefik https://docs.traefik.io/providers/docker/

Answer (score 0):

Documentation states [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) that:

> Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.

So I believe that you could just set your services names in that nginx conf file like:

```
upstream myservice {
    yourservice1;
    yourservice2;
}
```

as they would be exported as host entries in `/etc/hosts` for each container.

But if you really want to have that host:port information as environment variables you could write a script to parse that docker-compose.yml and [define an .env file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/env-file), or doing it manually.

**UPDATE:**

You can get that port information from outside the container, this will return you the ports

```
docker inspect --format='{{range $p, $conf := .NetworkSettings.Ports}} {{$p}} -> {{(index $conf 0).HostPort}} {{end}}' your_container_id
```

But if you want to do it from the inside of a containers then what you want is a service discovery system like [zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/)

There's a long [feature request thread in docker's repo](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3778), about that.

[One workaround solution](https://github.com/npalm/docker-discovery-agent) caught my attention. You could try building your own nginx image based on that.

Comment: I would like that the definition of the upstream myservice is created automatically with the scale definition